# mysql root password has been changed after database restored

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand why MySQL 5.1.73's root password has been changed from empty password to 'some_pw' after restored DB from another MySQL5.1.73 on CentOS 6.9.
I have setup Master/Master using MySQL 5.1.73 on CentOS 6.9 and it replicates without an issue, so I have mysqldump from existing DB and restored into one of the masters. BUT right after restore, the MySQL root password has been changed from empty pw to backup MySQL server's root password 'some_pw'.  Why does this happen?

Comment: If your dump includes the `mysql` database, that contains all the configuration information, including user passwords.

Comment: Are you really using MySQL 5.1.3? That was the very first beta release of the 5.1 branch, in 2005-11-29. It's undoubtedly very buggy, since it had many features that were not yet finished. You should at least be using the final release of 5.1.73, but you should ideally use a newer branch. The 5.1 branch is now ended.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the correct version.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the correct version. It is 5.1.73.  I guess mysqldump's  --all-databases option was causing the root password changes.Thanks guys.

Comment: That's still a rather old version of MySQL -- 5.1.73 was released in December 2013, and the 5.1 branch is no longer supported. You should upgrade to a supported version, if at all possible.

Comment: Understood, but one of our company's DB is still residing on MySQL 5.1.73 and have tried to upgrade from 5.1 to 5.5 to mariadb10, then Galera Cluster, but keep failing the migration due to DB index errors.  So my final solution to scale was master/master for now.